# Is it necessary to be partner with banks to write an NFC payment app?

Tags: android, nfc

Is it possible to implement NFC payment client without being partner with banks, if I don't generate virtual card numbers like Google Wallet?

**Update**:
I'm asking about the underlying technology of writing an NFC payment app -- if necessary hardware and programming techniques are supplied, does one need to specifically contact each bank to write such an app (e.g. provide encryption key and such)?

Comment: I don't think. In most country banking activities are regulated and required a legal agreement. But how is this question relative to programation ?

Comment: @sonic This is about making a mobile app, which is a program and requires programming... I'm actually asking about the underlying programming technique, I'll update the question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a specific code issue. Instead is about commercial agreements.

Comment: @DerGol...lum Please read the "off-topic" section in help center carefully. The questions here are not necessarily specific code problem.  This is "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

Comment: This is a **programming** Q&A site. Commercial and legal stuff is **off-topic**. Enough said.

Comment: @DerGol...lum I don't know why you saw this as a "Commercial" or "legal" stuff (did I mention them in my question?). Check out the answer and you'll see it's all technical.

Comment: Are you **kidding** me? Re-read your **question**: `Is it necessary to be partner with banks...` I don't see how this is not commercial and how it is "technical".

Comment: @DerGol...lum You've understood "partner" specifically in your way. My question body has explained what it means in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question has a lot of assumptions on it. You want a payment client, but what do you want to use for payments? We could be talking about digital wallets, bank accounts or things like bitcoins.

#### NFC Protocols

First, you must understand that NFC allows several protocols that you can use, and they are all [listed on the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/)

#### Visa / Mastercard integration

You can integrate with [Mastercard](https://developer.mastercard.com/product/mobile-payments-sdk) and  [Visa Token Service](https://developer.visa.com/capabilities/vts).

#### [Prepaid Cards / Smart Cards](http://www.smartcardalliance.org/smart-cards/)

There are several companies with pre-paid cards around the world. Maybe you can integrate with some of them. Not debit cards, but the ones [some transport agencies use](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2359_003.html). Although reproducing/emulating them without proper permissions might be illegal.

#### Or just make you own money

Yeah, why not. Imagine an arcade machines shop, where users can activate them by a prepaid system using the same protocols everyone else use. Since a lot of retro arcades nowdays are being build with things like [raspberry pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) which can easily have an NFC module too.

Of course, it would be a single purpose payment system... but fun to implement.

Comment: This is really useful. Thanks!

Comment: @Logain the links provided are broken

Comment: @ingkevin thanks, I just updated the links. I'm not 100% sure if Visa Tokens replaces PayWave, but that's the closer thing I found.